# Metalsmith layouts causes "no files to process" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, metalsmith

I conscientiously followed the tutorial on [official community driven docs](https://github.com/metalsmith/awesome-metalsmith/blob/master/tutorials/README.md) but failed to compile project on using Handlebars and metalsmith-layouts. "Metalsmith · no files to process" error occurred.

Here is my directory structure:

```
.
├── src
│   └── index.html
├── templates
│   └── main.hbs
└── build.js
```

build.js:

```js
const Metalsmith = require('metalsmith');
const layouts = require('metalsmith-layouts');

Metalsmith(__dirname)
    .source('./src')
    .destination('./docs')
    .use(layouts({
        engine: 'handlebars',
        directory: 'templates'
    }))
    .build(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    });
```

and main.hbs:

```html
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<p>
    {{contents}}
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `metalsmith-layouts` uses jstransformers.

You need to install `jstransformer-handlebars` in order to fix the error you encountered.

Run 
`$ npm install --save jstransformer-handlebars`
and try again.

Comment: Despite installing `jstransformer-handlebars`, `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\myname\Documents\projectname\templates\main.hbs'` error occurs. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, it's my stupid mistake. I placed `templates` folder wrong place.  It went right, thanks.

Comment: Good to hear that you were able to solve the issue. Could you please mark the answer as accepted?